# SQL max of a count involving 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, count, group-by, sql-order-by

I have one table `Customers` with `CustomerID` and `PhoneNumber`, the second table is `Orders` that has `CustomerId` and `OrderNumber` and a third table `OrderDetails` that has `OrderNumber`, `PriceOfOneUnit` and `UnitsOrdered`. I need to find the `PhoneNumber` for the customer who placed the largest order (`PriceOfOneUnit * UnitsOrdered`). Doing a `count(PriceOfOneUnit*UnitsOrdered)` as `A1` and then `Group By CustomerId Order By A1 DESC LIMIT 1 is evidently not working after joining the 3 tables. Can anyone help.

Comment: do you want to get the total amount of order or largest amount per order?

Comment: I need to find the person who invested the most money. Which means the highest number when number of items ordered by each customer is multiplied by the price of the ordered items. Thats is say Customer John ordered 2 units of shampoo priced at $5 and one unit of conditioner priced at $3 and customer  Jane ordered 4 units of soap priced at $1. My result needs to display John's informtion.

Comment: In the event of a tie, what would you like to see?

Comment: @user2204894 I get that but what I'm asking is do I need to calculate the total amount FOR ALL orders or I only to calculate the total amount PER order and get the highes invested money?

Comment: In the event of a tie I would need to show both.

Answer (score 0):

If we take you at your word, and what you want is the biggest single line-item rather than the largest order, you can find the largest line-item and then find the order to which it belongs and then the customer who placed that order.  You can use a dummy aggregate function to pull back the order id from orderDetails.

EDIT:
OK, for someone just starting out, I think it can be clearer to think in terms of Venn diagrams and use what are called Inline Views and subqueries:

```
select customername, phone
from customer
inner join

(

     select o.id, customerid from orders o
     inner join
      ( 
        select od.orderid from orderdetail od
        where (od.qty * od.itemprice) =
            (
              select max(od.qty * od.itemprice)
              from orderdetail as od
            ) 

      ) as biggestorder
    on o.id = biggestorder.orderid

 ) as X
on customer.id = X.customerid
```

Each of the queries inside parentheses returns a set that can be joined/intersected with other sets.

Comment: I know this is all sorts of wrong but I am just starting out. So I will appriciate any help with the edits.  select customers.customerName, customers.phone, orders.customerNumber, count(orderdetails.priceEach*orderdetails.Quantityordered )
from customers full join orders on customers.customerNumber=orders.customernumbers 
full join orderdetails on orders.orderNumber=orderdetails.orderNumber;

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT  cus.CustomerId, cus.PhoneNumber
FROM    Customers cus
        INNER JOIN Orders a 
            ON cus.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
        INNER JOIN OrderDetails b
            On a.OrderNumber  = b.OrderNumber 
GROUP   BY cus.CustomerId, cus.PhoneNumber
HAVING  SUM(b.PriceOfOneUnit * b.UnitsOrdered) = 
        (
            SELECT  SUM(b.PriceOfOneUnit * b.UnitsOrdered) totalOrdersAmount
            FROM    Orders aa
                    INNER JOIN OrderDetails bb
                        On aa.OrderNumber  = bb.OrderNumber
            GROUP   BY aa.CustomerId
            ORDER   BY totalOrdersAmount DESC
            LIMIT   1
        )
```